# Allow SeLinux to specific user can send email

Tags: selinux, zabbix

I'm trying to allow user zabbix to send email using **ssmtps**.
I've configured everything except SeLinux.
For **SeLinux** **booleans** there is no such item available for zabbix like httpd_can_sendmail.
PS: I can' send email when disable SeLinux. But I don't want to solve as this way.

`--------------------------------`
**UPDATE** **[PROBLEM** **SOLVED]**
`--------------------------------`
I solved it as following steps. I think it can solve many SeLinux related problems as this way if you have enabled audit logging.
1. `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep zabbix | grep denied >>
 /tmp/zabbix_mail_1`
2. Try send email through zabbix user.
3. Wait 2nd step's status, then `cat /tmp/zabbix_mail_1 | audit2allow -M zabbix_mail_1`   It will generate two files **zabbix_mail_1.te** and **zabbix_mail_1.pp** in current directory
4. `semodule -i zabbix_mail_1.pp` 
5. Loop above steps until there is no error on /var/log/audit/audit.log. You can increase index /tmp/zabbix_mail_**1** for next steps for the track what did you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--------------------------------`
**[PROBLEM** **SOLVED]**
`--------------------------------`
I solved it as following steps. This [blog](http://silviud.blogspot.com/2017/11/zabbix-server-under-selinux-centos-7.html) helped me. I think it can solve many SeLinux related problems as this way if you have enabled audit logging.
1. `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep zabbix | grep denied >>
 /tmp/zabbix_mail_1`
2. Try send email through zabbix user.
3. Wait 2nd step's status, then `cat /tmp/zabbix_mail_1 | audit2allow -M zabbix_mail_1`   It will generate two files **zabbix_mail_1.te** and **zabbix_mail_1.pp** in current directory
4. `semodule -i zabbix_mail_1.pp` 
5. Loop above steps until there is no error on /var/log/audit/audit.log. You can increase index /tmp/zabbix_mail_**1** for next steps for the track what did you do.

Answer (score 0):

Tool to view SELinux log information along with commands to allow the blocked command/process.

```
yum install setroubleshoot-server
```

Then to review the log

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Example output:

```
    *****  Plugin public_content (32.5 confidence) suggests   ********************

If you want to treat framework.css as public content
Then you need to change the label on framework.css to public_content_t or public_content_rw_t.
Do
# semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_t '/var/www/html/framework.css'
# restorecon -v '/var/www/html/framework.css'

*****  Plugin catchall (4.5 confidence) suggests   ***************************

If you believe that smbd should be allowed getattr access on the framework.css file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'smbd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-smbd
# semodule -i my-smbd.pp
```

As you can see above it is complaining about framework.css and provides a solution to allow.

*Note* - OS was not included so i assumed RHEL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't try your method. But looks good way. Because I solved it myself as similar way you suggest.

Comment: OS was RHEL 6.9